# Django: store value after user logs in or signs up

Tags: python, django

I need to create a random value when user stars session and store it after user **logs in** or **signs up**. Must be deleted after user logs out.

I'm using `session.session_key`, but could be anyother random value.

*Why `session.session_key`?* Because it gets automatically generated when user enters website.

When user enters website they can `add items` to their `shopping cart`, but cannot buy until `logs in` or `signs up`. All cart_items use the `random value` as a `token`, so if I can save this value after user logs in or signs up I can query the cart_items that are already saved in DB and restore items user had already put in this `shopping cart`.

So when user enters a new `session.session_key` is created but after user `logs in` or `signs up` another `session.session_key` is created. Making it impossible to use this value to establish a flow between user `not logged in` and `user logged in`.

**My logic**:

1.- Save `session.session_key` in Cookie.
2.- After user logs in or signs up a new `session.session_key` is created. We need to replace this new `session.session_key` with the one saved in Cookie.
3.- Get old `session.session_key` to query all objects created using this value as an ID and do stuff.

**Code**:

*cart id that need to be stored is generated with this function:*

```
def _cart_id(request):
    cart = request.session.session_key

    if not cart:
        request.session.create()  
        cart = request.session.session_key
    return cart  # Ultimately return cart
```

SignUp View:

```
@transaction.atomic
def signupView(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

      ...do stuff ...

    ### Save cart id in Cookie before authenticating
            set_cookie_values(request)
    ### Authentication
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)

            ### Get cart id from Cookie
            cart = request.COOKIES.get('cart', '')


            delete_cookie_values(request)

            return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
    else:

        profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list)
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
})
```

Helpers to store and delete value from Cookie:

```
def set_cookie_values(request):
    try:
        cart_id =_cart_id(request)
        response = HttpResponse()
        response.set_cookie('cart_id', cart_id, max_age=9999999999)

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass

    return response


def delete_cookie_values(request):
    response = HttpResponse()
    response.delete_cookie('cart_id')
    return response
```

I'd appreaciate your help checking out my pseudo code for storing cart_id on Cookie and retrive it.

**UPDATE 1:**

After Daniel Roseman's comment, I think I need to store the cart_id in session, delete it when user logs out, generate a new 1 when user ads a new item to the cart, delete it when logs out and so on.

I want to do it in the form that saves the OrderItem of user, but I don't know exaclty how to do it:

```
import secrets

# Create your views here.

def _cart_id(request):
    if 'cart_id' in request.session:
        cart_id = request.session['cart_id']
    else:
        cart_id = secrets.token_urlsafe(22)
    return cart_id
```

**Form Class:**

```
class StepTwoView(CreateView):
    form_class = StepTwoForm
    template_name = 'shop/subir-arte.html'
    success_url = '/cart/'


    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(StepTwoView, self).get_initial()
        initial['cart_id'] = secrets.token_urlsafe(22)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['product'] = Product.objects.get(
            category__slug=self.kwargs['c_slug'],
            slug=self.kwargs['product_slug']
        )
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):

        try:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(self.request))
        except Cart.DoesNotExist:
            cart = Cart.objects.create(
                    cart_id = _cart_id(self.request)
                )

            cart.save()

        self.request.session['cart_id'] = self.initial['cart_id']

        form.instance.cart = cart
        form.instance.product = Product.objects.get(
            category__slug=self.kwargs['c_slug'],
            slug=self.kwargs['product_slug']
        )  # get tamanios from session
        form.instance.size = self.request.session.get('size')  # get tamanios from session
        form.instance.quantity = self.request.session.get('quantity')  # get cantidades from session
        del self.request.session['quantity']  # delete cantidades value from session
        del self.request.session['size']  # delete tamanios value from session
        self.request.session.modified = True
        return super(StepTwoView, self).form_valid(form)
```

But I'm getting:

```
KeyError at /shop/stickers/stickers-cuadrados/subir-arte

'cart_id'

self.request.session['cart_id'] = self.initial['cart_id']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing things the wrong way round. The session key is renewed when a user logs in, but the contents of the session are preserved. So what you should do is to give the cart a separate random ID, and store that in the session.

Comment: ty for the hint. I'll try this new approache.

Comment: ty. I've solve it. I was complicating myself too much.